# Securing Apache Solr in production

Tags: web-applications, solr, full-text-search, jetty, search-engine

We are using Apache Solr 4.1 to index data for a web app. Only the web app should have access to the Solr. Users and other clients will not directly talk to Solr.

What are some of the best practices to secure this type of Solr use case?

(we are using Jetty to run Solr)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, just a few of the options available:

1. Don't expose the Solr server URL to the browser, make sure only the web app can see it and issue queries to the Solr server (SolrJ and Solr.Net are good clients to use for this).
2. Don't allow any other URL to communicate with your Solr server host except the web app server.
3. Use a proxy to obfuscate the Solr server URL and disallow certain queries and URLs ( and admin).

Comment: Thanks Chris. Do you have some config files that you can share?

Comment: 1) in this case, the query will be executed from compiled code so the Solr server URL will not be visible to the web user 

2) this means the server OS/VM gets network configuration to restrict network traffic between Solr and web servers 

3) (do something like this)[https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ajax-solr/pLtYfm83I98]

Does that help?